# user-space specified to interpreted language

Tags: javascript, memory-management, operating-system, v8

does program written in interpreted language (eg..Javascript) can have a low user space than a program written in some compiled language ? 
my point is programs with compiled languages the os brings it into main memory give it Virtual space say 4 GB in contrast with program written in interpreted language who runs already on a top of process that has 4 GB memory allocated for it
to be clear enough i give you and example 2 identical programs written in c++ and the other in javascript , python whatever now the c++ program can allocate data up to 3 GB (Virtual memory after remove space specified to OS) and js programs can allocate data say 2 GB (virtual memory after removing os and interpreter headache) 
is my point right ? or am i missing something ?
does the memory available for allocation for complied program the same as interpreted one ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of the compiled vs. interpreted javascript in java7 / Rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538541/performance-of-the-compiled-vs-interpreted-javascript-in-java7-rhino)

Comment: i don't see that help !! it speaks about performance and i am speaking about memory available for programs !!

Answer (score 0):

How much memory a program can allocate is generally independent from which language it was written in, and also independent from whether that language is typically compiled or interpreted. (Note that the latter distinction is not always clear, as some "interpreters" perform just-in-time compilation under the hood; and some languages are first compiled to a bytecode which is then interpreted.)

*Some* runtime environments, for example V8, impose fixed limits on the amount of memory a program can allocate. In case of V8, you can control the heap size with command-line flags. As a  counter-example, as far as I know Python does not impose a fixed limit on programs (it takes system memory into account).

It's fair to assume that "interpreters" (i.e. runtime environments for "interpreted" languages) consume a bit of memory themselves, which *can* mean that the executed program itself has a little less memory to play with than the entire process does. However, nothing prevents "compiled" languages from performing certain allocations upon process startup (for libraries, or "system-provided" things, or whatever), so it really depends on what environments exactly you are comparing.

Also, in practice, the data structures used can vary wildly in their implementation, which can have a big impact on effective memory limits. For example, consider a "hash map": different implementations of the C++ standard library might make different tradeoffs affecting memory consumption for a given number of map entries; different JavaScript engines might have different implementations that might consume more or less memory for the same number of entries than a C++ version would.